# How can I align the tops of a group of div elements after changing height via jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm using jQuery to iterate over three div elements grouped in a section element, and equalize their height. While that part works perfectly, the divs are left vertically uneven where their bottoms were aligned before. The divs seem to be shifted down on the page the amount jQuery added to their height, respectively.

Here's a [non-problematic jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BenjaminRH/QpsXk/embedded/result/) (I don't change the heights), and [one with my problem](http://jsfiddle.net/BenjaminRH/YL7ZG/embedded/result/) (I change the heights and it messes up the divs).

Here's my CSS:

```
section.myGroup {
    text-align : center;
}

.myBlock {
    margin : 10px;
    padding : 10px;
    text-align : justify;
    display : inline-block;
    width : 275px;
    background-color : #ffffff;
    background-image : url('images/background.png');
    background-repeat : repeat;
    position: relative;
}
```

And here's my HTML:

```
<section class="myGroup">
    <div class="myBlock">
        <p>Lorem ipsum bla bla bla....</p>
    </div>

    <div class="myBlock">
        <p>Lorem ipsum bla bla bla....</p>
    </div>

    <div class="myBlock">
        <p>Lorem ipsum bla bla bla....</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

EDIT: Here's the jQuery I use to equalize the height of the divs. It's pretty standard:

```
var tallest = 0;

$('.myBlock').each(function() {
    var thisHeight = $(this).height();
    if (thisHeight > tallest) {
        tallest = thisHeight;
    }
});

$('.myBlock').height(tallest);
```

Comment: Show us the part that works perfectly and the other one too.

Comment: I added the jQuery I use to equalize their heights, although I believe it's completely standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the complication comes in because you are unable to use 'float: left'.  The workaround is to go ahead and use 'float: left', but then you will have to use 'margin: auto' to center your section.  The limitation though, is you will have to specify the width for your section:

http://jsfiddle.net/YL7ZG/3/embedded/result/

```
.myGroup {
    width: 576px;
    margin: auto;
}
.myBlock {
    margin : 10px;
    float: left;
    padding : 10px;
    text-align : justify;
    width : 150px;
    background-color : #ccc;
    border: solid black 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use this code - It should be work

```
function equalHeight(group) {
    var tallest = 0;
    group.each(function() {
        var thisHeight = $(this).height();
        if(thisHeight > tallest) {
            tallest = thisHeight;
        }
    });
    group.height(tallest);
}

    equalHeight($('section.myGroup .myBlock'))
```

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/bZXFH/

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea. Unfortunately it doesn't work, and also I wouldn't want to restrict the container because the .myBlock divs need to be in one column when in a smaller window, such as a mobile browser.